# Meteor: can I define a namespace for global helpers?

Tags: meteor, namespaces, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I would like to do something like this defining global helpers:

```
// namespace Strings

Template.registerHelper('Strings.truncate', function(s, l) {
  // ...
});

Template.registerHelper('Strings.ellipsis', function(s) {
  // ...
});

// namespace Format

Template.registerHelper('Format.currency', function(s) {
  // ...
});

Template.registerHelper('Format.integer', function(s) {
  // ...
});

// etc
```

But I get an error when I try to use one of those helpers:

```
{{ Strings.truncate 'some string' 5 }}
```

> `Uncaught Error: Can't call non-function: null`

Is there a way to give some sort of namespacing to global helpers?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it, simply I can use the [square brackets syntax in handlebar](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/spacebars/README.md#identifiers-and-paths) in this way:

```
{{ [Strings.truncate] 'some string' 5 }}
```

So I can give a name with a dot (`.`) to global helpers and have a kind of namespacing.